# How to trim white spaces in Go templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I would like to trim white spaces in Go templates. How would I do that?

Example:

```
 {{ $title = " My Title of the product " }} 
 
 // Print the trim string here
 <h1>{{ $title }}</h1>
```

Comment: "trim whitespace" usually means remove whitespace from the beginning and end of a string. There is no whitespace at the beginning or end of your string--and even if there were, it wouldn't matter in HTML output, where extra whitespace is ignored. So your question is very unclear.

Comment: In case you're looking for how to remove white space in-between template *actions* then you can use `-` as documented [here](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Text_and_spaces).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing built in that will trim string "pipelines" for you inside a template, however you could use the [`strings.TrimSpace`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace) function inside a template if you provide it to that template with the [`Funcs`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) method.

```
var str = `{{ $title := " My Title of the product " }}

// Print the trim string here
<h1>{{ trim $title }}</h1>`

t := template.Must(template.New("t").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "trim": strings.TrimSpace,
}).Parse(str))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/g0T7shJbDVw.

Answer (score 0):

if you want "My Title of the product" to MyTitleoftheproduct you can use that func

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
     "strings"
     "strconv"
)

func main(){
    s:= "a b c d "
    n:=trimW(s)
    fmt.Println(n)
    //abcd
}

func trimW(l string) string {
    var c []string
    if strings.Contains(l, " ") {
         
        for _, str := range l {
             
            if strconv.QuoteRune(str) != "' '" {
                c =append(c,string(str))
            }
         
        }
        l = strings.Join(c,"")
    }
    return l
}
```

Comment: This does not work with go templates, which the question is asking about.

Comment: It's also incorrect in that it only works if the input contains a literal space, not any whitespace, and it only removes Unicode characters which quote to a literal space, which is not all white space. It's also terribly inefficient.